# Codeigniter: Retrieve insert_ids using insert_batch()

Tags: php, codeigniter, activerecord

Is there a way to grab all the insert ids ( using $this->db->insert_id() ) from a previously run insert_batch() method?

Ideally it will spit out a simple array of the ids in the order they were inserted.

Comment: Not for codeigniter,but it will help you some amount..Please go through http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285231/php-mysql-retrieving-the-last-inserted-ids-for-multiple-rows

Comment: Thanks duke, guess I just assumed that the insert_id output the LAST inserted row, not the first. This is good information and I will be using this method instead of trying to parse into an array.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

creating a trigger would work.

not sure if its gona affect performance on huge batch insertion

```
DELIMITER $$

CREATE
    TRIGGER `test`.`getids` AFTER INSERT
    ON `database_name`.`table_name`
    FOR EACH ROW BEGIN
        INSERT INTO last_inserted_ids (last_insertId) VALUES(LAST_INSERT_ID());

    END$$

DELIMITER ;
```

it will get all the ids into the table, as you want them in an array write a query which run exactly after the batch and gets all the values from table `last_inserted_ids` and then truncate it so that you always have the desired ids after a batch is executed.

hope this helps your case.

Comment: This is a pretty cool concept, and I will mark as accepted answer because it does what I asked for, allowing me to parse into array. But for performance purposes, and the fact that I'm not doing anything funky with auto incrementing, I will go with dukes comment. Thanks!