# Get inserted row ids in PHP and MySQL with multiple inserts

Tags: php, mysql

MySQL code is something like:

```
INSERT INTO table(name, value) VALUES ('name1', 'value1'), ('name2', 'value2'), ('name3', 'value3')
```

Basically, multiple inserts in the same SQL statement.

How can I get the IDs of the inserted values. I assume mysql_insert_id() combined with the number of inserts isn't safe since someone else might insert something at the same time.

Is there another way?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1285231/php-mysql-retrieving-the-last-inserted-ids-for-multiple-rows

Comment: Thanks vimalnath, didn't find that one.

Answer (score 2):

You either need to insert them one at a time or figure out the id's with a followup query.

```
INSERT INTO table(primkey, value) VALUES ('pk1', 'val1'), ('pk2', 'val2');
SELECT FROM table id, primkey where primkey in ('pk1', 'pk2');
```